# Average value of a function at infinity

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a nonnegative and continuous (possibly smooth) real valued function such that \begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int^x_0f(y)\,dy=0
\end{equation}
Does it follow that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$?

My attempt: At least when $F(x)=\int^x_0f(y)\,dy\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ we can appeal to L'Hospital's rule, provided that also $\lim_{x\to\infty}F'(x)$ exists, to obtain $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int^x_0f(y)\,dy=0\Leftrightarrow\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}F(x)=0\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F'(x)}{(x)'}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}F(x)=0$$$$\Leftrightarrow\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$ 
However when $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)<\infty$ I can not see an immediate reason for $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. Does this vanishing behavior occurs also in this case? If not, is there a necessary/sufficient condition on $f(x)$ to guarantee this vanishing behavior?

Comment: What about $f(x)=\cos(x)$ ?

Comment: That is not "nonnegative".

Comment: Your application of L'Hôpital's rule is incorrect. L'Hôpital's rule says that if you already know the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$, then it is the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ in some circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your hypothesis it does not follow that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to\infty$. Indeed, take a smooth function equal to zero everywhere except in a small neighborhood of $x=0$, on which it is strictly positive. Call this function $g(x)$. Then take $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(x - 2^n)$. That is, $f$ is equal to zero most of the time, except identical "bumps" around the points $x = 2^n$. Clearly $f$ does not have a limit as $x \to\infty$ but the average value of $f$ is still zero. (Prove that as an exercise.)

Comment: Thank you. This is an insightful example.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit counter-example is given by:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x-e^n)}{x-e^n}\right)^2. $$
The integral over $[0,M\gg 1]$ of $f(x)$ is bounded by $4\log M$, hence $f$ has mean value $0$, but $f(x)\geq 1$ for any $x$ in the set $\{1,e,e^2,e^3,\ldots\}$.